# What causes the rollback of changes in postgres with asp net core?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, linq2db

My web application has many methods that open the context to the database. As an ORM quality, I use a linq2db. When I try to update some existing record in the database, it seems to me that a rollback occurs. But For some time in the database the correct version of the record is available with changes

Comment: It's probably a missing `commit` rather than an explicit rollback

Comment: Isn't a commit executed automatically in the using construct?

Comment: no, transaction disposal performs rollback if transaction wasn't commited explicitly

Comment: I began to use commit in every database action. But transactions keep rolling back